# Why does boolean cut not work

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make a hole in this simple box with the Boolean modifier but it doesn't work.
Delete loos, Merge by distance, Face orientation, Scale, Recalculate normals, I've done all of them but it still doesn't work.
What am I overlooking?
[image]

Comment: It probably is working, but since the cylinder is still visible, you can't see the hole in the box.  Go to the cylinder in the outliner and click the eye to make it invisible.  Does that show the hole?

Comment: I know, but unfortunately not

Comment: Try switching from exact to fast solver in that case.  Exact solver seems very buggy.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either

Comment: I made the cylinder longer so that it also extends above the top. Then I gave the top of the cover a face and then did the boolean, then it worked. Then I removed the excess face.

Comment: That's weird, but I'm glad you've found a solution.